# Get Username in another model for friendlyId custom slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I'm using FriendlyId.
At the moment i build a custom slug this way:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :photo_by_author, :use => :slugged

 def photo_by_author
   "#{title} by #{user_id}"
 end

belongs_to :user

end
```

And my slug it's like: `/photo-title-by-7`
Instead of `7` I want to get the `username` of the `user = 7`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Delegate**

How about the good old [`.delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method:

```
#app/models/photo.rb
Class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   delegate :username, to: :user
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
def photo_by_author
   "#{title} by #{username}"
 end
```